# IGeometry 'MakeValid' Error using EF core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, spatial, ef-core-2.2

I'm using EF core 2.2 with a project that has an IGeometry object ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial ) , and i'm running an 'Intersects' query against some of the spatial data in my database.  Sometimes however i get this error:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "geometry":   System.ArgumentException: 24144:
>   This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid.
>   Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that
>   MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift
>   slightly

now when i was in pure SQL not using EF core, i could just use MakeValid to fix it, but i don't see anything like that in C#. Closest i see is the 'IsValid' option ( https://nettopologysuite.github.io/html/class_net_topology_suite_1_1_operation_1_1_valid_1_1_is_valid_op.html )

Is there a MakeValid for EF Core that i'm not finding?

Comment: have you added UseNetTopologySuite() function to OnConfiguring method in your context?
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-2/

Comment: yes i have.  The spatial object works fine for the most part, it's just some data needs to be massaged, and some doesn't